# putExtra() and getBooleanExtra() in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I'm developing an app that implements mapsView. I have two activities that lead to the mapsView activity. activity_A will lead to mapsView activity, and the mapsView activity will lead to the activity_B. I'm implementing `putExtra()` and `getBooleanExtra()` in my code.

Here's my code in activity_A

```
case R.id.buttonMaps:
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("maps", false);
    startActivity(i);
break;
```

Here's my code in activity_B

```
buttonNavigasi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent i = new Intent(DetailActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
        i.putExtra("nama", daftarNama);
        i.putExtra("deskripsi", daftarDeskripsi);
        i.putExtra("foto", daftarFoto);
        i.putExtra("marker", daftarMarker);
        i.putExtra("lat", daftarLat);
        i.putExtra("lng", daftarLng);
        i.putExtra("maps", true);
        startActivity(i);
     }
});
```

Here's my code in mapsView activity

```
case R.id.action_refresh:
     removeAllMarkers();
     if(i.getBooleanExtra("maps", true)) {
         mMyMarkersArray.add(new MyMarker(i.getStringExtra("nama"), i.getStringExtra("deskripsi"), i.getStringExtra("foto"), i.getStringExtra("marker"), Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra("lat")), Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra("lng"))));
         UI_HANDLER.postDelayed(UI_UPDATE_RUNNABLE, 500);
     }
     else {
         registerReceiver(mNetworkReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
     }
     getCurrentLocation();
     return true;
```

The problem is when the mapsView go to activity_B and in activity_B I pressed the back button (back to mapsView activity) then I pressed the refresh icon in mapsView, the mapsView will go to this code

```
if(i.getBooleanExtra("maps", true)) {
     mMyMarkersArray.add(new MyMarker(i.getStringExtra("nama"), i.getStringExtra("deskripsi"), i.getStringExtra("foto"), i.getStringExtra("marker"), Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra("lat")), Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra("lng"))));
     UI_HANDLER.postDelayed(UI_UPDATE_RUNNABLE, 500);
}
```

Why it doesn't go to the `else` statement in mapsView activity? I do not press the `buttonNavigasi` in activity_B, but I just press the back button. What's wrong with my code?

Any answer will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you press back button your previous activity is just resumed

```
private boolean registerRecr=false;

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onRestart();

    registerRecr=true;


}
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onStart();

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

}

 case R.id.action_refresh:
 removeAllMarkers();
 if(i.getBooleanExtra("maps", true)&& registerRecr==false) {
     mMyMarkersArray.add(new MyMarker(i.getStringExtra("nama"), i.getStringExtra("deskripsi"), i.getStringExtra("foto"), i.getStringExtra("marker"), Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra("lat")), Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra("lng"))));
     UI_HANDLER.postDelayed(UI_UPDATE_RUNNABLE, 500);
 }
 else {
     registerReceiver(mNetworkReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
 }
 getCurrentLocation();
 return true;
```

Answer (score 1):

Because when you do not assign any value he get by default true `i.getBooleanExtra("maps", true)` try with `i.getBooleanExtra("maps", false)`:

```
case R.id.action_refresh:
     removeAllMarkers();
     if(i.getBooleanExtra("maps", false)) {
         mMyMarkersArray.add(new MyMarker(i.getStringExtra("nama"), i.getStringExtra("deskripsi"), i.getStringExtra("foto"), i.getStringExtra("marker"), Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra("lat")), Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra("lng"))));
         UI_HANDLER.postDelayed(UI_UPDATE_RUNNABLE, 500);
     }
     else {
         registerReceiver(mNetworkReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
     }
     getCurrentLocation();
     return true;
```

**EDIT**

Following the life cycle of an activity when you press back button maybe this solution in `MapsActivity` could be more useful for you:

```
Intent i;
boolean refresh=false;
//YOUR CODE
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //YOUR CODE
    i = getIntent();
    //YOUR CODE
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
    //YOUR CODE
        if(i!=null){
                refresh = i.getBooleanExtra("maps", false);
        }
    //YOUR CODE 
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        //YOUR CODE
        i=null;
       //YOUR CODE 
    }
    //YOUR CODE
    case R.id.action_refresh:
     removeAllMarkers();
     if(refresh) {
         mMyMarkersArray.add(new MyMarker(i.getStringExtra("nama"), i.getStringExtra("deskripsi"), i.getStringExtra("foto"), i.getStringExtra("marker"), Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra("lat")), Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra("lng"))));
         UI_HANDLER.postDelayed(UI_UPDATE_RUNNABLE, 500);
     }
     else {
         registerReceiver(mNetworkReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
     }
     getCurrentLocation();
     return true;
     //YOUR CODE
```

Hope help

Comment: I have added this code too `@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        i.putExtra("maps", false);
    }`
but still not work :(

Comment: You don't need to handle onBackPressed try with my code and tell me.

Comment: this is the way that getBooleanExtra works:getBooleanExtra(String name, boolean defaultValue), if don't exist this key in the hash map get the default value

Comment: But i have an activity_A that lead to the mapsView activity. In activity_A, there's code like this `i.putExtra("maps", false);`

Comment: You do not talk about the behaviour of Activity_A you are asking about Activity_B, and I really don't know what you are doing in activity_A an what are the results. Sorry, I think I'm useless in this question.

Comment: Is there any solution for this case? Where should i put this code `i.putExtra("maps", false);` ? whether in `onCreate ()` or maybe in `onBackPressed` ?

Answer (score 1):

`if(i.getBooleanExtra("maps", true)) {`

Here you are telling it to get `maps`, if it doesn't exist it will simply be true.

If you set it to false, you will get the correct answer.

Comment: I have added this code too @Override public void onBackPressed() { i.putExtra("maps", false); finish(); } but still not work :(

Answer (score 0):

you could override your own onBackPressed

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

}
```

to force the user to navigate through your buttons or to pass through the onBackPressed the value of the boolean that you want

or you could simply `finish()` each activity after using the `startActivity()` so you won't use too much memory in the same time avoid those loops that way you can only start the map through the intent