# getBooleanExtra() always get true value

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm developing an app that implements mapsView. I have two activities that lead to the mapsView activity. activity_A will lead to mapsView activity, and the mapsView activity will lead to the activity_B. I'm implementing `putExtra()` and `getBooleanExtra()` in my code.

Here's my code in activity_A

```
case R.id.buttonMaps:
    Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MapsActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("maps", false);
    startActivity(i);
break;
```

Here's my code in activity_B

```
    buttonNavigasi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent i = new Intent(DetailActivity.this,MapsActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("nama", daftarNama);
            i.putExtra("deskripsi", daftarDeskripsi);
            i.putExtra("foto", daftarFoto);
            i.putExtra("marker", daftarMarker);
            i.putExtra("lat", daftarLat);
            i.putExtra("lng", daftarLng);
            i.putExtra("maps", true);
            startActivity(i);
         }
    });
```

Here's my code in mapsView activity

```
    case R.id.action_refresh:
         removeAllMarkers();
         if(i.getBooleanExtra("maps", true)) {
             mMyMarkersArray.add(new MyMarker(i.getStringExtra("nama"), i.getStringExtra("deskripsi"), i.getStringExtra("foto"), i.getStringExtra("marker"), Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra("lat")), Double.parseDouble(i.getStringExtra("lng"))));
             UI_HANDLER.postDelayed(UI_UPDATE_RUNNABLE, 500);
         }
         else {
             registerReceiver(mNetworkReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
         }
         getCurrentLocation();
         return true;
```

The problem is when the mapsView go to activity_B and in activity_B I pressed the back button (back to mapsView activity) then I pressed the refresh icon in mapsView, the mapsView will go to the `if` statement. Why it doesn't go to the `else` statement in mapsView activity? I do not press the `buttonNavigasi` in activity_B, but I just press the back button. What's wrong with my code?

Any answer will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if condition should be `if(!i.getBooleanExtra("maps", false))` means when not `true` then execute if block and if true then execute else block

Comment: My question is why it always get true value when i set the putExtra to the false value?

Comment: I mean, your button in activity_B is setting the extra to true and starting a new intent. If you aren't utilizing that code in the issue in question, don't post it. What does `removeAllMarkers` do?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to expect that `getBooleanExtra` compares the value to the second argument. The second argument is the default value which is returned if the value is not found. `getBooleanExtra` returns `false` because that is the value you just set there.

Comment: Yeah, why it always get true value when i set the putExtra to the false value?

Comment: If you reach the `else` block it didn't return `true`, it returned `false`. That is the definition of an if-else statement.

Comment: Why?  i have initialize false value in if condition like this `if(i.getBooleanExtra("maps", false))`

Comment: You are misunderstanding basic java syntax. Please take a step back and learn about basic conditional statements in java.

Comment: I have activity_B that leads to this activity too. I set `i.putExtra("maps", true);` in activity_B. And the result is it will go to the `else` statement and not to `if` statement. So what's wrong here?

Comment: you most likely reference a wrong intent. But that is another question and should be asked seperately.

Comment: hi @F43nd1r, i have already change `i.putExtra("maps", false);` to `i.putExtra("maps", true);` in activity_A but the result is it always go to the else statement in mapsView activity. why?

Comment: That means the default value is used. Are you sure i is the correct intent instance?

Comment: Can you spend a little time to see my question in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36430268/putextra-and-getbooleanextra-in-android

Comment: Sorry, the full explanation of my question in this post is in that link.

Comment: You still did not add any additional code. I need to know where `i` comes from in `i.getBooleanExtra`.

Comment: I have initialize `i = getIntent();` in `onCreate()`

Comment: And in which part of the lifecycle is the code you posted?

Comment: Sorry, i don't understand what you mean.??

Comment: Is the getBooleanExtra also part of the onCreate or is it in another activity method?

Comment: The getBooleanExtra will get value from another activity.

Comment: Hi @F43nd1r, do you have solution for my question?

Comment: Hi @F43nd1r, do you have solution for my question?

Comment: Sorry I currently have no time to walk you through debugging.